# Unable to have user role permissions correctly applied

Tags: users, 9

I have a multi-language site managed by different admins. We want to create a news editor role and apply it so that a) the person can only modify content applicable to their language and b) can only modify content type "news"

I am using the translation module and also installed the "content access" module.

Under permissions, I have the permissions correctly configured under "node" in user permissions, where I only allow CRUD for the "news content type", and relying on the translation modules to restrict content to their languages under the users > languages section.

My site is applying the correct permissions for translations, only allowing you to edit assigned languages (or translate another language content type), but simply ignores the "node" rules and allows me to edit any language assigned to my user role. I then tried the content access module, but unfortunately even those rules were ignored. Although under node I only allow modifications of the content type "news", I am able to edit any content type.

I suspect there is a hierarchy of permissions and my access is probably granted because of the permissions set to accept modifications of assigned languages and then ignores the node permissions, or does the permission system continue?

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Comment: In Drupal, permissions cascade, so users will always have maximum access based on the permissions they have been granted.  Try removing permissions one-by-one to determine which permission is giving too much access. `Although under node I only allow modifications of the content type "news", I am able to edit any content type.`-- This is almost certainly a misconfiguration/incorrect setting somewhere in your config.  You may have accidentally given users permission to `Administer content` or something like that.

Comment: I have unticked all permissions (even media) and only left viewing of admin template and then the CRUD's associated to "news" content type, results stays the same. Only when in "allowed languages" (module) if I untick a language, I am now no longer able to edit that node. I assume that allowed languages takes preference and ignores the additional permissions. What is my options? I have noted that "content access" module has a "weight" but setting it to -10 or 10 (0 is default) has no affect

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue with the `Allowed languages` module: https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_languages/issues/3228286.  That's a scary bug and given that it's sat for half a year unresolved, I would hesitate to use such a module.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bugs in modules are off-topic for *Drupal Answers*.  Bugs need to be handled in the Drupal issue queues.

Comment: I can confirm it is related to the bug. I was able to fix it by running the hotfix. Don't have a choice in running the allowed languages module for now so will keep an eye out on progress over time. Thank you